# AJAX and PHP not communicating through post method

Tags: php, ajax

So I have an html form thats a quiz with 8 questions. I have a javascript that adds up the score and gives back a grade, I want to display it but also save the grade to my database through ajax post method to a php file. Now I have a few catch commands for my ajax code that comes out successful, it spits out the value that i want, however after the fact, my php code seems to have never ran. I dont get any of my catch errors from my php code.

my javascipt and ajax:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
     q1 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q1"]:checked').value);
     q2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q2"]:checked').value);
     q3 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q3"]:checked').value);
     q4 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q4"]:checked').value);
     q5 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q5"]:checked').value);
     q6 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q6"]:checked').value);
     q7 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q7"]:checked').value);
     q8 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q8"]:checked').value);



       result = q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6 + q7 + q8;

    document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = result;


        $.ajax({
          url: 'quiz1.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data : {result : result},
          success: function (data){

          },
          error: function (data){
            alert("failed to save data");
          }


       });

   }
```

and then my php: (i tried a few things in there to get results but nothing even shows signs of the php file even being called)

```
<?php

include("phpbook-vars.inc");
$database="yr1005";
$connect=mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password);
if(!$connect)
  echo "<h2>Error occurred, failed to connect with MySQL:</h2>".
  mysqli_connect_error()."</b>";
if(!mysqli_select_db($connect, $database))
  echo "Database $database not selected";

  if(isset($_POST['result'])) {
      $score = $_POST['result'];
      echo $score;
  } else {
      echo 'fail';
  }

$query = "INSERT INTO quiz1 (username, quiz1)
VALUES ('anything', '$score)";

if(!mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
  echo "<h2>Error - couldn't save quiz grade</h2>";
  header ("refresh:3; url=hciQ.html");
} else {
  echo "<h2>Thanks your grade was recorded</h2>";
  header ("refresh:3; url=hciQ.html");
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Hint: In the PHP file, look _very closely_ at quote matching. Also, check the browser console `F12, then the console tab` to ensure no errors are logging. Check the webserver logs for potential PHP errors too.

Comment: ...also in the PHP file, there should not be any output before the header redirects. It would be better to use `error_log` to send that output to the webserver log. However, for the message before each `header` call, you can move those to just after the header call since there is 3 sec refresh. See [this example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#97114) where the message is after the header call.